# Changing font and colour of text in Eclipse text editor

Tags: eclipse, fonts

If I open a text file which doesn't have a specific editor (such as Java or C/C++) in Eclipse how can I change the font and color of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font can be changed using the Colors and Fonts page in the preferences dialog. Go to **`Project->Preference->General->Appearanc->Colors and Fonts`**. Open Basic and select `Text Font` and click Edit...

To change the text color you need to go to a different page of the preferences dialog, **`Project->Preference->General->Editors->Text Editors`** and modify the Appearance color options for Foreground and Background color